# My app returns a crash related-to androidView

Tags: android, imageview, android-studio-3.0

I'm doing a splash screen for my application.

The splash consists in two images:

- one as background,
- the other as text over the background.

The problem is that when I run the app, it returns this error:

```
03-04 00:31:57.921 21298-21298/org.waylan.smartjack E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.waylan.smartjack, PID: 21298                                                                  

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.waylan.smartjack/org.waylan.smartjack.Splashscreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3255)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:474)
      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2388)
      at org.waylan.smartjack.Splashscreen.onCreate(Splashscreen.java:29)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3208)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:474) 
      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2388) 
      at org.waylan.smartjack.Splashscreen.onCreate(Splashscreen.java:29) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3208) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:474) 
      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2388) 
      at org.waylan.smartjack.Splashscreen.onCreate(Splashscreen.java:29) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3208) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 16768736 free bytes and 55MB until OOM
      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4211)
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4085)
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3935)
      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
      at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4226)
      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:150)
      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:145)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:474) 
      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2388) 
      at org.waylan.smartjack.Splashscreen.onCreate(Splashscreen.java:29) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3208) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I know that the error is related to my **activity_splashscreen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/lin_lay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/splash"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="visible">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/splash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/texto" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Curiosly, when I launch the app with virtual emulator of Android Studio, it works perfectly, but when I plug my phone (Galaxy S5 Neo, with Android 6.0.1), this crash occurs.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: what is the settings of you emulator? does google play services updated to latest version on your phone?

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError` - Your images are too big.

Comment: Sounds like the emulator was given more memory than your physical device, or there's just more stuff running on your phone